# Why does Convert.ToInt32 of a char returns the ascii code?

Tags: c#, char, int

Why does this code prints the 48 (ASCII code for 0) instead of 0?

```
char c = '0';
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(c));
```

Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: What should Convert.ToInt32('%') return then?

Comment: zero! if it was a string that yould be the return. I just wanna know if there is any special reason for this

Comment: If you really want it to convert the _readable_ contents to the appropriate number, look at [Integer.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.Parse(v=vs.110).aspx). The thing is that '0' is just one of the visual symbols that can be stored in a char, and the visual circle with a line through it doesn't mean anything to the computer - just to humans.  The '0' is just a visual symbol, whose Unicode/Ascii value is 48 in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because, as [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ww9t2871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), Convert.ToInt32 Method (Char) returns:

> A 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded **code point** of the value parameter.

and code point means:

> In character encoding terminology, a code point or code position is any of the numerical values that make up the code space. For example, ASCII comprises 128 code points in the range 0h to 7Fh

and from just logic point of view, what result would you expect from `Convert.ToInt32('a')`? Convert is for type conversion, not for interpretation. Interpretation can be done by Parse-kind methods.

Comment: OK I could understand it a little better with the last paragraph. Many thanks for your answer, I was expecting it to behave like a string, this was just out of curiosity.

Comment: The `Char` [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and for the C# alias `char`, the C# docs) are a bit more correct on this. `Char` holds a UTF-16 code-unit. So, `Convert.ToInt32(Char)` would return the UTF-16 code-unit represented by the `Char`. UTF-16 encodes Unicode codepoints in one or two code-units.

Comment: basically (int)'0' converts 0 like that too so you would expect it would be the same as Convert.ToInt32('0'), this is because of the C. How it converts this.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what the overload you're calling does. You're expecting it to behave the same as `Convert.ToInt32(string input)` but actually you're invoking `Convert.ToInt32(char input)` and if you check the docs, they explicitly state it will return the unicode value (in this case the same as the ASCII value).

Docs here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I checked the docs now, I just wanted to know if there is any special reason for this, like is it helpfull in any specific case?

Comment: @Xikinho90 I'm sure there are many situations where a developer might want to know the utf value of a character. I personally haven't run into one anytime recently so I can't give a concrete example but someone who works more with character encodings and text processing probably could provide several.

Comment: +1 for "the Unicode value (in this case the same as the ASCII value)." Even in the shrinking parts of computing that don't use Unicode, the use of ASCII is extremely limited.

Answer (score 2):

you should do this

```
 char c = '0';

 Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(c)));
```

To be fancy

```
 char c = '0';

 Console.WriteLine(c - '0');
```