# Convert Int32 to String

Tags: string, vb.net, int32

I have a small piece of code that converts a string to Int32

```
Dim sample As String = "H۩llo!"
For Each c As Char In sample
    Dim enc As String = Convert.ToInt32(c)
    Console.Write(enc + " ")
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

This will convert the text to Int32
Output:

```
72 1769 108 108 111 33
```

But is there a way to conver the output back to "H۩llo!"?

Comment: another option is `Dim chars = int32Chars.Select(Function(n) Char.ConvertFromUtf32(n))` and then you do `Dim text = String.Join("", chars)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it back to the original string with

```
Dim nums As Int32() = { 72, 1769, 108, 108, 111, 33 }
Dim cs As Char() = nums.Select(Function(x) Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(x)).ToArray()
Dim s = New String(cs)
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Console.WriteLine(s)
```

Comment: That works but the output is now "H?llo!" is there anything to return the ۩?

Comment: Not sure what is your problem. I see the original character ۩ in my output.

Comment: Code:
https://pastebin.com/w6cprscS

Output:
https://pastebin.com/uMPaz5Zq

Comment: Found the problem, you need to set the output encoding. Updating the answer

Comment: That worked in the console there is a [?] symbol but when copying it to internet there's a ۩ thank you! +1

Comment: I thought Convert.ToInt32(c) was UTF-16 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578376/2516718